# How to pass value from activity to broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am developing one application using broadcastreceiver i have problem with receive value in broadcast receiver from activity,please tell me how to send value from activity to broadcast receiver and how to receive value  in broadcast receiver from activity ,i am trying like below code but its not working

my code
 in activity side

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
    //intent.setAction("IncomCallBroadCast");
    intent.putExtra("contact",phNo);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in broadcastreceiver side

```
 String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
    if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
        contact = intent.getExtras().getString("contact");
        Log.e("",contact );
    }
manifest
<action android:name="my.action.string"/>
```

Comment: you are not getting your contact printed in the log ?

Comment: yes i want to get contact in log

Comment: show us the line declaring `phNo` variable.

Comment: its getting nullpointer exception

Answer (score 2):

In main activity use this code to start broadcast receiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent("package.action.string");
intent.putExtra("extra", phoneNo); \\ phoneNo is the sent Number
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the broadcast reciver use this code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 String action = intent.getAction();

 Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

 if(action.equals("package.action.string")){
   String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

  }
}
```

NOTE : Donot forget to declare your Broadcast receiver in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <action android:name="package.action.string" />
    <!-- and some more actions if you want -->
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
String action = intent.getAction();
contact = intent.getExtras().getString("contact");
```

to

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
contact = intent.getStringExtra("contact");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `phNo` is of type String. If not, use `getInt()` in your `BroadcastReciever`.

You might want to add a `String` in extras, and retrieve back in `String`.
If the type of `phNo` variable is int, then you should retrieve the extra value in the form of `int` only.

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
Log.e("i am printing my cotnact " , contact );
```

and give me some feedback

Hope that Helps .