# Trying to pass value to Broadcast Receiver from Activity crashes Application

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a value to a Broadcast Receiver from Activity based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422656/how-to-pass-value-from-activity-to-broadcastreceiver) question.

However, doing so crashes my application. Here is my code of the Activity.

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{

    Intent in = new Intent("my.action.string");
    in.putExtra("ALARM_NO", tempx);
    sendBroadcast(in);

    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

And here is the Broadcast Receiver code as well:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    int state;
    String action = intent.getAction();

    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

    if(action.equals("my.action.string"))
    {
        state = intent.getIntExtra("ALARM_NO",0);

    }

    if(state==1) {

        //intent to call the activity which shows on ringing
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Time_Date.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    if(state==2)
    {
        //intent to call the activity which shows on ringing
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmLaunch2.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

And this is what i obtain in the logcat.

```
> 07-21 16:40:40.769  26721-26721/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia, PID: 26721
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2616)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:29)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

So , whats causing the null pointer exception? and how to fix this ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should base on answer, not question ;)

Comment: yes, I used the code from the Answer

Comment: what is written in 29 line

Comment: Why are you sending an intent to the  BroadcastReceiver? What should do your code?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi if(action.equals("my.action.string"))

Comment: @Joseph82 are you advising me to go for a shared preference rather than passing using Intent?

Comment: No, I was not understanding why you are using sendBroadcast(). You just need to pass your intent, to a pendingIntent, and then pass it to the alarmmanager. And you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{
    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("ALARM_NO", tempx);
    alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

> alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string");

Answer (score 0):

> **You can compare by using putExtra itself**

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
    {
        Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
     alarmintent .putExtra("action", "my.action.string");
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

    }
```

> **getStringExtra("action") in broad cast receiver**